# Ubuntu 20.04 , xwiimote cannot use it as a mouse

Tags: 20.04, wii

i am able to use the wii remote controller, but i can't use it as a mouse.

I changed /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/60-xorg-xwiimote.conf to:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Nintendo Wii Remote"
MatchProduct "Nintendo Wii Remote"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Option "Ignore" "off"
Option "MotionSource" "ir"
Option "MapIRA" "left-button"
Option "MapIRB" "right-button"
Driver "xwiimote"   
EndSection
```

but i didn't work.

Any idea's ?

Answer (score 1):

To get the Left and Right click mouse buttons working you need to change

```
Option "MapIRA" "left-button"  ---> Option "MapA" "left-button"
Option "MapIRB" "right-button" ---> Option "MapB" "right-button"
```

To move the cursor you'll need to point the wii remote at a sensor bar if you don't already have one attached to the screen.